# Methods for asymptotic expansion of $a_{n+1}= f(n,a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Suppose that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined by following induction schema
$$a_{n+1}= f(n,a_n)$$

where $f$ is a smooth map (of two variables). What methods/theorems can be used to find the asymptotic expansion of $\{a_n\}$?

I’m conscious that the answer is not unique and will be more a list of options depending on the particular form of $f$. For example when $a_{n+1} = a_n +g(a_n)$.

Comment: May be we follow the strategy of Contractions Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration

Comment: Even without the dependence on $n$ such recurrences can get extremely complicated: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map for some examples.